# How To Choose The Bounty Winner For A Subjective Question?

Tags: discussion

I have offered a bounty and am having problems deciding how to award it. My [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11923208/781200) is about a specific problem but solutions are subjective and many. I have received excellent answers several of which I would happily award the bounty to.

In particular, one [late answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12080140/781200) provides the most complete solution *if* the technologies behave as outlined. I will need a lot of time to be certain this solution works but the bounty must be awarded within 24 hours.

I would appreciate any advice on how to manage this.

Comment: Wow! You just got another answer on your question!  Excellent question by the way!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best people to help evaluate your answer may actually be the answerers themselves. My suggestion is to edit your question and ask the answerers to fill in the missing pieces. Get *them* to convince you which solution is the best.

If you have concerns about the late answer, leave comments challenging your doubts and get the poster to respond. You may very well get feedback from another poster that sways your opinion one way or another.

Lastly, be aware that chat could be a good tool for evaluating these answers, especially if Stack Overflow has a chat room for iOS development. You could then discuss the question using technologies that are more suited to actual discussions. If you're going to be around for the next 23 hours, you could leave a link to the chat room in the comments and even entice the answerers to join you in the conversation.

I see you have a lot of answers to sort through. Good luck determining which one is the best!

Comment: You are absolutely correct of course. And I have asked for more input in a comment. I hesitated because it feels like a _demand_ on people who are already helpful. Now I can blame you if anyone calls me pushy. :) Thanks.

Comment: My "blaming you" line was a joke. But sometimes jokes are not obvious online. I hope you were not offended in any way and of course I take responsibility for my comments.

Comment: @Polly - lol no, your joke came through perfectly. ;)  Just FYI, it's generally accepted that on bounties the requirements will be a little tougher. Remember, you put up a significant amount of your reputation for this! ;)